# How to raise an event on page go back on .Net Maui?

Tags: maui

I have .Net 7 Maui page A.

From the page A, I'm navigating to page B using :

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageB());
```

I need to run a code on Page A when the user navigates back from Page B to Page A. Means the code needs to be run when Page A is active again.

I tried the following events : **Focused**, **NavigatedTo** but that's not the right events. **Focused** is not firing, the **NavigatedTo** is fired when navigating from a page toward page A et not navigating back from page B to Page A.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have only two pages:

```
public partial class PageA : ContentPage
{
    public PageA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Button click to trigger event
    async void NavigateToPageB(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageB());
    }

    public void PopTo()
    {

    }
}

public partial class PageB : ContentPage
{
    public PageB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Button click to trigger event
    async void NavigateBackToPageA(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
      //Alternatively you can write linq to find the page name
      var pageA = (PageA)Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.FirstOrDefault();
      pageA.PopTo();
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        var pageA = (PageA)Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.FirstOrDefault();
        pageA.PopTo();

        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This indeed works when a button in my app is clicked. But not when when the user clics "go back" button of his mobile.

Comment: I have updated the answer for back button clicked scenario

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Page.OnAppearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page.onappearing?view=net-maui-7.0) Method in page A：

```
protected override void OnAppearing()  
  {  
        base.OnAppearing();  
  }
```

When overridden, allows application developers to customize behavior immediately prior to the Page becoming visible.
You can refer to my previous answer in this thread([Navigationpage NavigatedTo event not working on IOS when going back - Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75627122/navigationpage-navigatedto-event-not-working-on-ios-when-going-back-maui/75646558#75646558:%7E:text=1-,Answer,-Sorted%20by%3A)).

Comment: This is not working. This event fires when the page is shown for the first time but not when navigating back to the page. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I used the code provided by @Himanshu Dwivedi. And I added the following lines that take into account the case when the user clicks back button of the mobile phone instead of my button on the app :

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    //Do what is expected to be done on Page A Here
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user returns back to my main page after visiting another, I've set a listener for the "NavigatedTo" event of the ContentPage view. The event is raised when the page first loads (obviously) and again when the user returns to the page from another but *not*, alas, when the user returns to the page after visiting a popup.

in the XAML, I give the ContentPage a name:

```
 x:Name="conContent"
```

and in the code behind I add a listener:

```
conContent.NavigatedTo += ConContent_NavigatedTo;
```