# pass information to a previous page with xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a page where there are buttons that take me to a view, in this there is a form and I want that when it is filled out and they hit the save button, it returns me to the previous page and there it shows the data that the user entered.

I have tried to send it as a parameter to the constructor but it does not work for me.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting, and please [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+pass+data+to+previous+page+site:stackoverflow.com) first too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to raise an event on page go back on .Net Maui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75763351/how-to-raise-an-event-on-page-go-back-on-net-maui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

**Method 1**:A common approach is to use `EventHandler`.

You can define `EventHandler` in the second view(Suppose the name is SecondPage), just as follows:

```
 public static EventHandler<Item> mEventHandler; // define a static  EventHandler
```

After you fill the form in the second page, you can pass the data with the following code:

```
   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<Item> handler = mEventHandler;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.Name = mNameEntry.Text; //mNameEntry is a Entry of this page
                item.Email = mEmailEntry.Text;//mEmailEntry is a Entry of this page

                mEventHandler(this, item);
            }

            Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
```

`Item.cs`

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

In the previous page(e.g. `MainPage`), you can add the following code in the constructor of Your PreviousPage .

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Secondage.mEventHandler += delegate (object s, Item a)
        {
            BackCall(s, a);
        };
    }

    private void BackCall(object send, Item obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
        }
        else
        {

            DisplayAlert("Alert", "call back value Name : " + obj.Name +" ,emails :" + obj.Email, "OK");
        }
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync( new Secondage());
    }
}
```

**method 2**

You can also use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to achieve this function.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage 
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // method 2

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SelectedPage, Item>(this, "SelectedItem", (obj, item) =>
        {
            var newItem = item as Item;

            DisplayAlert("Alert", "call back value is : " + newItem.Name, "OK");

        });

    }
 }
```

SecondPage.xaml.cs

```
   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
         Item item = new Item();
         item.Name = mNameEntry.Text; //mNameEntry is a Entry of this page
         item.Email = mEmailEntry.Text;//mEmailEntry is a Entry of this page

        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "SelectedItem", item);

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```